# loopback: custom model serialization

Tags: loopbackjs

The general question is: how to hook into loopback's serialization process (model 2 json coversion).
The more concrete example is: I need to add `@type` field to each model (nested models too) returned from loopback api server.

Comment: You can do anything in https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html or override `toJSON` method of each model

Comment: As for now I need to implement `after('**')` hook and make manual model serialization (with walking whole tree of models). Just looking for better way to do it.